# WP7 Set public string value from web service query

Tags: linq, windows-phone-7

I'm trying to bring back information from a web service and then use that piece of information throughout my project but cannot figure out how to set a public string from a web service query. At the moment, i've hard coded the id into the public string. How do I replace the hard coded value with the value returned by query?

```
public MainPage()
    {
        WebClient id = new WebClient();

        id.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(UsernameSetting, PasswordSetting);
        id.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(id_DownloadStringCompleted);
        id.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri("https://web-service-address/"));
    }

    void id_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Error != null)
            return;

        XDocument xDocument = XDocument.Parse(e.Result);

        var myid = xDocument.Descendants("service").First();
    }

    public string IDSetting = "1234567";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can assign the value of myid to IDSetting at the end of id_DownloadStringCompleted()

```
IDSetting = myid;
```